# MS Graph API - I can read users in B2C Active Directory but cannot create users

Tags: azure, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am using azure functions to serve as a secure api between my front end application and MS Graph.

I have a B2C AD for which I am able to get a single user and list all users, using my azure function.

I get 401 unauthorised when I try to create a user.

My API app is registered in B2C with permissions Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All, Application.ReadWrite.All, AuditLog.Read.All and User.ReadWrite.All - all of them indicate they have admin consent.

Client secret is in order and is used as part of the token request.

I get the access token from the [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant) id}/oauth2/v2.0/token end point. This is how I obtain the token:

```
const APP_ID = 'XXXXXXX';
const APP_SECERET = 'XXXXXXXX';
const TOKEN_ENDPOINT ='https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/token';
const MS_GRAPH_SCOPE = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default';
const MS_GRAPH_USER = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"

const axios = require('axios');
const qs = require('qs');

const postData = {
    client_id: APP_ID,
    scope: MS_GRAPH_SCOPE,
    client_secret: APP_SECERET,
    grant_type: 'client_credentials'
};

let token = null

await axios
.post(TOKEN_ENDPOINT, qs.stringify(postData))
.then(async (response) =>  {

    token = response.data.access_token}) etc etc etc...
```

Error response is simply a 401 Unauthorised. I can post the full message if required.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

[image]

Error response looks like this:

```
 response: {
status: 401,
statusText: 'Unauthorized',
headers: {
  'cache-control': 'private',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'request-id': '93918a37-f0ed-44c9-85ad-d22157e88239',
  'client-request-id': '93918a37-f0ed-44c9-85ad-d22157e88239',
  'x-ms-ags-diagnostic': '{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"UK South","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"4","ScaleUnit":"002","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_40"}}',
  'www-authenticate': 'Bearer realm="", authorization_uri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize", client_id="00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000',
  date: 'Tue, 15 Dec 2020 15:20:10 GMT',
  connection: 'close',
  'content-length': '302'
},
config: {
  url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users',
  method: 'post',
  data: 'accountEnabled=true&mailNickname=TT&passwordProfile%5BforceChangePasswordNextSignIn%5D=true&passwordProfile%5Bpassword%5D=XXX',
  headers: [Object],
  transformRequest: [Array],
  transformResponse: [Array],
  timeout: 0,
  adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
  xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
  xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
  maxContentLength: -1,
  maxBodyLength: -1,
  validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  Authorization: 'Bearer XXX (removed)'
},
request: ClientRequest {
  _events: [Object: null prototype],
  _eventsCount: 7,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  outputData: [],
  outputSize: 0,
  writable: true,
  _last: true,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: false,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
  sendDate: false,
  _removedConnection: false,
  _removedContLen: false,
  _removedTE: false,
  _contentLength: null,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: true,
  _headerSent: true,
  socket: [TLSSocket],
  connection: [TLSSocket],
  _header: 'POST /v1.0/users HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
    'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n' +
    'User-Agent: axios/0.21.0\r\n' +
    'Content-Length: 127\r\n' +
    'Host: graph.microsoft.com\r\n' +
    'Connection: close\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
  agent: [Agent],
  socketPath: undefined,
  method: 'POST',
  insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
  path: '/v1.0/users',
  _ended: true,
  res: [IncomingMessage],
  aborted: false,
  timeoutCb: null,
  upgradeOrConnect: false,
  parser: null,
  maxHeadersCount: null,
  reusedSocket: false,
  _redirectable: [Writable],
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
  [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
  [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
},
data: { error: [Object] }
```

},
isAxiosError: true,
toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}

EDIT:

Tried graph explorer and despite having consent for each of the permissions I get a 403 forbidden

[image]

I've asked my global admin to confirm but I think I have the application administrator role.

Also, as my registered app has granted admin permissions I thought this would have worked as it does not rely on my permissions...?

Thanks

Comment: can you please provide the correlation id and timestamp of error message

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity I have added an error response to the body. Couldn't explicitly see the attributes your requested

Comment: Let us know which role you have and also can you please try this using [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and share the error details if you are facing any issue( correlation id and timestamp)

Comment: Thanks @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity - I have added details of the graph explorer feedback as well as some comments. Look forward to hearing from you

Comment: can you please provide request-id and timestamp in the text format

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity "date": "2020-12-15T19:55:52",
            "request-id": "74915cd6-71f9-4a7e-b733-907928025e1e",
            "client-request-id": "d9055a37-5e3c-72b8-2acf-9d147227dfc3"

Comment: can you please add the role as [User Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#user-administrator) and try the same API in graph explorer

Comment: Can you share how you get the access token in your code?

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity with user administrator the API works in graph explorer. However, it is not adding a user to B2C (which i guess is expected). So, now I have user admin, how can I create a user in B2C?

Comment: @AllenWu I have added the javascript I use to get the token (which works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below code for getting the user list and Create a new user

```
 const request = require('request');
    let tokentest='';
    const endpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    const requestParams = {
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
        client_id : "clientid",
        client_secret : "secret",
        scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    };
     user = {
      accountEnabled: true,
      displayName: "Adele Vance",
      mailNickname: "AdeleV",
      userPrincipalName: "AdeleghhhVgghhh@xxx",
      "passwordProfile" : {
        forceChangePasswordNextSignIn: true,
        password: "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
      }
    };
        
    
    request.post({ url:endpoint, form: requestParams }, function (err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Body=" + body);
            let parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);         
            if (parsedBody.error_description) {
                console.log("Error=" + parsedBody.error_description);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Access Token=" + parsedBody.access_token);
    
               createGraphAPI(parsedBody.access_token);
                testGraphAPI(parsedBody.access_token)
            }
        }
    });
    
    function testGraphAPI(accessToken) {
        request.get({
            url:"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users",
            headers: {
              "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
            }
            
        }, function(err, response, body) {
            console.log(body);
        });
        
    }
    
    
    function createGraphAPI(accessToken) {
      request.post({
          url:"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users",
          headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
            'content-type': 'application/json'
           
          },json:user
        
    
          }, function(err, response, body) {
            console.log(body);
        });
        
    }
```

Comment: thanks @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity but i don't see how that differs from the code I'm already using.

Comment: I have a feeling that the fact my app is registered in my B2C tenant and not my AAD tenant and that may be the problem...

Comment: No that wasn't it. I still get 401 unauthorised

Comment: can you please make sure you are passing the access token correctly and have you tried the above code by replacing you are clientid,tenantid, and secret.

Comment: {
  error: {
    code: 'Authorization_IdentityNotFound',
    message: 'The identity of the calling application could not be established.',
    innerError: {
      date: '2020-12-17T14:19:00',
      'request-id': '0e2bb9bb-968c-4be0-a412-a939dba034ef',
      'client-request-id': '0e2bb9bb-968c-4be0-a412-a939dba034ef'
    }
  }
}

Comment: I got more information using your code. That is the error message I got when I try to create a user in the B2C tenant

Comment: change the app ID and secret to the app registered in my B2C tenant (as opposed to the one in my AAD tenant, I get this error:

code: 'Request_BadRequest',
    message: 'The domain portion of the userPrincipalName property is invalid. You must use one of the verified domain names in your organization.',
    innerError: {
      date: '2020-12-17T14:29:25',
      'request-id': 'd620830d-e75f-414a-9f40-f81a5671d68c',
      'client-request-id': 'd620830d-e75f-414a-9f40-f81a5671d68c'
    },

Comment: Please change you are  domain name in upn  like"AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com", to AdeleV@b2c.onmicrosoft.com while creating user

Comment: that worked. Thank god! As this is B2C I want my users to be able to login with their email and so that won't be xxx.onmicrosoft.com - it will be joe@whatever.com - is this going to be possible?

Comment: I think perhaps this explains: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#example